# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a 'To Do List' for exercise. but something is wrong.
please somebody help me.

I wannna make a fucntion to delete a list which is done
But It doesn't work and chrome send me a message:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
How can I make deleteTodos work properly?

```
var hi = $("#hi");
var button = $("#button");
var input = $("#input");
var ol = $('#ol');
var CB = $('#CB');

var inputTag = '<input type="checkbox" id="CB">'
var DeleteBtn = '<button id="btn">x</button>'

  
function deleteTodos (event){
  var removeing = event.target.parentElement;
  removeing.remove();
}

$("#button").click(function enter (text) {

  var All = '<li id="text">'+inputTag+input.val()+DeleteBtn+'</li>'
  ol.append(All);
  input.val("");

  $('#btn').click(deleteTodos());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#btn').click(deleteTodos());
```

to

```
$('#btn').click(deleteTodos);
```